# Get the emails of the stargazers for a repo in github using python

Tags: python, github-api

Actually trying to get the

1. `users(stargazers)` for a repo in github by using the `github api`
2. `Emails` of all the stargazers

So for the `first point` i had tried the below command

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/my_username/my_repo_name/stargazers
```

**result**

I had got results in the form of json dict something like below

```
[
  {
    "login": "gazer_name",
    "id": 17xxx,
    "avatar_url": .........,
    "gravatar_id": "....",
     .......
     .......      
    "type": "User"
  }

  {
    "login": "hello_man",
    "id": 18xxx,
    "avatar_url": .........,
    "gravatar_id": "....",
     .......
     .......      
    "type": "User"
  }
  ......
  ......          
]
```

So now according to the second point, i want to get the emails of all the users ?
so how can we do that with `github api` ? `whether we need to login for sure in order to get the emails ?`

Because we can get the user email by using the command `GET /user/emails` as described [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/users/emails/)

That means something like `curl -u "my_user_name" https://api.github.com/user/emails` only after `logging in`

And how to use `GET /user/emails`  exactly because when i entered in to terminal as it is the result is nothing, but when i used `authentication with curl` like above its displaying emails, which indicates that login is required inorder to get user emails
So how can we get the emails of the `stargazers` ?

Comment: So you want to be able to spam github users without even logging in?

Comment: Oh... not for that purpose :).But we had functions/pacakges like github3 for providing more functionality for getting commit history including the user details etc., but trying something new

Comment: I'm with @Wooble. This seems very suspicious and you're already using my library which would make this too easy.